# Java web application fails on one instance and passes on another with the same version

Tags: ubuntu, java, tomcat

I am running a java web application on tomcat on a docker container on Ubuntu on two machines. Both have the same OS version

```
Linux version 3.19.0-77-generic (buildd@lcy01-03) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) #85~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 5 11:19:02 UTC 2016
```

I have made sure that the war files are the same, the libraries loaded are of of the same version in both cases.

However, it gives a `Null Pointer Exception` on machine and works fine on another.

How should I go about debugging this issue?